# Migrate from .Net core 2.2 to .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

Hi I am trying to Migrate Web API from .Net core 2.2 to .net core 3.0 I am getting warning for the below lines code. Could you please let me know how to fix this.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

  {  
 var buildServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var getService = buildServiceProvider.GetService<IOptions<ConfigurationSettings>>();
            ConfigurationSettings = getService.Value;

}
```

> Warning:Calling BuildServiceProvider from application code results in additional copy of singleton services being created.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are creating ServiceProvider. Ideally, you should not call services.BuildServiceProvider(). it looks like you are calling `BuildServiceProvider` so that you can resolve `IOptions<ConfigurationSettings>`. instead of resolving in the `ConfigureServices` method you can accept `IOptions<ConfigurationSettings>` as an argument of the service and ASP.NET Core will inject it into your service.

```cs
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyService(IOtherService otherService, IOptions<ConfigurationSettings> configurationSettings)
    {
         // read config value from here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be useful to include the info about calling `services.Configure<ConfigurationSettings>()` to bind the config mapping in `Startup.cs`.